# Как оптимизировать или усовершенствовать функцию?

Tags: python, pytorch

Имеется torch-тензор с булевыми значениями `(False, True)`. Мне нужна функция, которая возвращает `True`, если в булевом тензоре только один `True`. Я написал такую функцию, но внешний вид функции мне не нравится.
Сама функция:

```
def is_contain_only_one_true(tensor: torch.Tensor) -> bool:
    return tensor.nonzero().numel() == 1
```

```
import torch
>>> a = torch.tensor([True, False, False, True])
>>> is_contain_only_one_true(a) # 2 True
False
>>> b = torch.tensor([True, False, False]) # Тут один True
>>> is_contain_only_one_true(b)
True
```

Функция отрабатывает и возвращает ожидаемый результат, но с предупреждением:

```
<ipython-input-4-a3e0f370a666>:2: UserWarning: This overload of nonzero is deprecated:
    nonzero()
Consider using one of the following signatures instead:
    nonzero(*, bool as_tuple) (Triggered internally at  ../torch/csrc/utils/python_arg_parser.cpp:766.)
  return tensor.nonzero().numel() == 1
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь более прозрачный способ добиться того же результата?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так предупреждение не выдаёт:

```
torch.nonzero(tensor).numel() == 1
```

Наверное, логичнее всего сделать так, только на выходе будет не просто `bool`, а `tensor(bool)` (который легко превращается в обычный `bool`):

```
torch.sum(tensor) == 1
```